# Need control over the audio stream in webchat

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

Is there a way to pause and play the audio output from the custom speech endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the BotFramework-WebChat [actions](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/packages/core/src/actions), in particular `startDictate`, `startSpeakingActivity`, `stopDictate`, and `stopSpeakingActivity`. These actions are accessible via Web Chat's redux store and will provide you *some* control over the audio play (I only say "some" as I haven't played with these extensively, so I can't speak fully on them).

However, it is relatively easy to attach these actions to Web Chat activities / events or to user interactions on the hosting page (i.e. a button click or some other). There are various [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples) found on the Web Chat repo that can guide you on setting up.

In short, your code might look something like the below. This example demonstrates the 'stopDictate' action being issued via an event listener that is triggered when Web Chat receives a specific incoming event from the bot or user.

```js
<script>
  (async function() => {

    const store = ({ dispatch }) => action => next => {
      if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY') {
        const { activity } = action.payload;
        if (activity.type === 'event' && activity.name === 'sendStopeDictateEvt') {
          const stopDictateEvent = new Event( 'StopDictateEvent' );
          window.dispatchEvent( stopDictateEvent );
        }
      }
      return next( action );
    };

    [...]

    window.ReactDOM.render(
      <ReactWebChat
        directLine={ window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }) }
        store={ store }
      />,
      document.getElementById( 'webchat' )
    );
  } );

  window.addEventListener('StopDictateEvent', () => {
    store.dispatch({
      type: 'WEB_CHAT/STOP_DICTATE'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Hope of help!

Comment: Hi @Steven this solution gives us control to certain extent but my use case is something like this. We have integrated webchat in an angular project. Let's say the bot says something like "here are your orders". i need to click a button after the bot finishes speaking. An endpoint which gives me a duration for a said utterance would be ideal. For eg: i give the "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs" as input and i get 4 seconds as the output. It takes the bot 4 seconds to complete speaking the input in the selected voice.

Comment: So, in other words, you are wanting a way to time how long it takes the bot to speak an utterance?

Comment: Yes, also a way to pause the speech based on a flag change in the ui code rather than an event would be very helpful